# Restful, Proxy and webapi

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a consumer app for a publically avalible rest webservice.

 I'm having 2 problems: My proxy and the service authentication.

 i cant seem to get past my proxy, actually i do have a valid credential to get by it, but i dont know where or how to provide it!

 And second, i also dont know how to responde the basic authentication challenge issued by the web-service...

I do can use it via browser, but i cant get it working on my c# app. Heres the code so far:

```
HttpClient cli = new HttpClient();
cli.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myserver.com/");            
HttpResponseMessage response = cli.GetAsync("api/service1").Result;

textBox1.Text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

the result in textBox1 so far is always a 407 error... Can anyone help?

Edit1: Authentication on the webservice is of the type BASIC!
Edit2: clientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "P@ssw0rd"); does not work... server returns "This request requires HTTP authentication"

Answer (score 3):

Proxy information needs to be configured on the HttpClientHandler object which can be passed into the HttpClient constructor.

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```

For credentials I do something like this...

```
    var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() {PreAuthenticate = true};

    var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new Uri(Host), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(userName, password));
    clientHandler.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

By setting this up this way, whenever you make a request to any URI that is below the "Host" URI, HttpClientHandler will automatically set the correct authorization header.

Also, be aware there is an alternative handler called WebRequestHandler that can be used instead of HttpClientHandler that add in extra stuff that is only available on the Windows OS like WinINet proxy and Pipelining.